# use a fullname as a Java regex pattern to match first or last name

Tags: java, regex

If a user can only enter a single string search term to find users by name, and users have names stored as First and Last name strings, then I would like to use the input string to search by either first name, last name, or both.

While it's possible to conditionally split the input, and then match the first and second strings against both the first and last names, there's a lot of logic there, and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to turn the whole string into a regex pattern that will match

For example:

If the user enters "John Doe", I would like it to retrieve users with the first names "John" or "Doe", and the last names "John" or "Doe", as well as "John Doe". I would like "John" to also return users with first or last names "John". I am looking for the most efficient way to do this, preferably without having to split the input string by any possible white space.

```
final String searchTerm = "John Doe";
pattern = Pattern.compile(/* some regex pattern */, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
results = usersCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("$or", new BasicDBList() {
            {
                add(new BasicDBObject("firstName", pattern));
                add(new BasicDBObject("lastName", pattern));
            }
        })
);
```

without the simple regex pattern for the whole search term, I would have to be

```
final String searchTerm = "John Doe";
String[] parts = searchTerm.split(" ");
firstPattern = Pattern.compile(parts[0], Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
secondPattern = Pattern.compile(parts[1], Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
results = usersCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("$or", new BasicDBList() {
            {
                add(new BasicDBObject("firstName", firstPattern));
                add(new BasicDBObject("lastName", secondPattern));
/*AND*/
                add(new BasicDBObject("firstName", secondPattern));
                add(new BasicDBObject("lastName", firstPattern));
            }
        })
);
```

and also there would need to be conditional logic to detect a string that is a single name, like "John", to eliminate the split and compare first and last name to a single string. This is all pretty tedious and if a single regex patter is possible it would be preferable.

Comment: Why don't you want to split the input?

Comment: while it's possible to conditionally split the input, and then match the first and second strings against both the first and last names, there's a lot of logic there, and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to turn the whole string into a regex pattern that will match

Comment: The way I'm thinking of it, there's not a lot of logic. You should just do `username.contains(first) || username.contains(last)` or something.

Comment: I've added some example code to show what I'm talking about. rather than splitting the name and using each part as a separate regex pattern, I'm wondering if there's a way to turn the whole name string into a single search pattern. to me it seems cleaner than having to match each name part against the first AND second part, and then also accounting for cases where there is only a single input name with no spaces, and matching both first and last against that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `replaceAll` whitespaces (`\s`) to regex or sign (`|`). Now you can simply use this pattern.

```
String test = "John Doe";
String regex = test.replaceAll("\\s", "|");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("John");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
System.out.println(matcher.start());

matcher = pattern.matcher("xJohn");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
System.out.println(matcher.start());
```

If you want to not match *xJohn* on search of *John* then change:

```
String regex = "^" + test.replaceAll("\\s", "|") +"$";
```